# How to calculate double value upto 2 decimals, but without rounding off the digits

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a double number for e.g "12.1278", I want to convert this number up to 2 decimals only, like "12.12".

But, when I use following code:

```
double d = 12.1278;
NSLog(@"Float upto 2 decimals : %.2f", d);
```

The output is:

> Float upto 2 decimals : 12.13

I want the conversion like:

> Float upto 2 decimals : 12.12

Comment: Multiply by 100, take the integer part, divide it by 100, here you go !

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` with `roundingMode` of `NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor`.

```
double d = 12.1278;

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(d)];

NSLog(@"numberString: %@", numberString);
```

NSLog output:

> numberString: 12.12

Comment: why not use round down? Why choose to use RoundFloor?

Comment: It was an arbitrary decision. `NSNumberFormatterRoundDown` is indeed a good choice, perhaps better. The choice depends on how -1.555 should be rounded: -1.56 or -1.55 with `setMaximumFractionDigits:2`.